# Making an app like Udacity - How to host video files?

Tags: android, video-streaming, video-encoding, cloud-hosting, video-player

I'm building an Android app that works similar to Udacity app.

My requirements

1. All my videos should only be viewed via the app.
2. I will be using my own video player inside the app, and I want the
   option to choose quality of video (Like in YouTube app)
3. Offline download option

Considering these requirements, how would I want to host the videos?

I'm familiar with the Android app side of things, but the rest I know nothing.

Did 3 hours of googling before posting this question here, and found out udemy is using AWS and Brightcove.

Can anybody explain the procedure of hosting and encoding videos for my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, big organizations like Udemy, Coursera and Udacity design and develop their own video encoding tool to show in the application. Udacity, for instance, has two modes - YouTube and their own player which the user can set based on their preference.

You can't develop your own codec or player in a jiffy, it needs a lot of dedication and more work which one person cannot develop in days.

For your query, you can use ExoPlayer, YouTube Embed, Vimeo Player, related kinds of open source or publically available players.